# GWT chinese mouse select event

Tags: javascript, gwt

[image]I have a problem with catching event when user selects chinese symbols from drop-down that appears below textbox using mouse. If I select it using numbers or using spacebar, the onKeyUp event is triggered. But when I select right symbols from dropdown, it doesn't trigger any event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT surfaces events that the browser dispatches, it doesn't do anything fancy for keyboard events (this is too much of a mess; higher-level events could be possible, but definitely not trying to *normalize* browser behaviors by synthesizing or suppressing low-level events). That means that if you don't receive a `KeyUpEvent` here, that's because the browser doesn't dispatches one.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#events-composition-event-key-events which says that:

> During the composition session, all `keydown` and `keyup` events **MAY** be suppressed.

Unfortunately, GWT doesn't expose the more recent and higher-level `input` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input (note that it still wouldn't work in old IEs, basic support only comes in IE9 according to the compatibility table at the end of that page)